# How to scrape hidden fields ('Click to display' fields)

Tags: import.io

I am looking for a way to scrape data from click to display fields using import.io

Example link: http://otomoto.pl/oferta/audi-a5-3-0-tdi-sportback-ID6y548D.html

When you click on red button - 'Wyświetl numer' just below main photo on the left, it shows you a number. I would like to scrape those numbers using import.io

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import.io does allow for scraping the fields behind a button using xpath. Any field that you can access via "inspect" is scrapable.

For your example, try some XPath like this

//*[@id="body-container"]//a

and you'll have to use the Manual XPath feature of import.io. You have to click "enter" for the xpath to register and highlight hte element of interst.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you are going to be able to do that since the number is loaded via java-script , also as long the number is not in the html then you can't get it with import.io .

Comment: There is no way to use connector to record click actions?

Comment: no there is no way to do this even with connector , cause it records for example search form before the data page .

Comment: Yes, you will not be able to extract the long number, even with an xpath. The number is indeed loaded with javascript so even trying to load via connector would not be successful.

Comment: Is this correct? Import.io [claims that it supports JavaScript](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/265494-crawler-faq).

Comment: it supports java-script but what the op is asking for is that import.io is able to get the data behind an onclick element which only possible if the application can press the button and this is not possible